# Java 8 sort using a specific range

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a Distance object which have a totalDistance attribute.
Using java 8 steams I need to sort a List by the totalDistance.

I know that I could sort this list by using something like:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Distance::totalDistance).reversed())
```

My problem though is that I need to sort it by a specific range.

For example, sort the distance getting the first 50, then getting from 50 to 100, and so on... but through those intervals it should not be ordered.

For example, with the following list:

```
List<Distance> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Distance(100));
list.add(new Distance(10));
list.add(new Distance(1));
list.add(new Distance(40));
list.add(new Distance(30));
```

Sorting by range I would get:

```
10,1,40,30,100
```

Any Idea of how to implement this kind of sorted range interval using java 8?

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly certain that you can divide the value by your range's length (`50`, in this case) when comparing them:

```
List<Distance> list = Arrays.asList(new Distance(130),
            new Distance(100), new Distance(10),
            new Distance(1), new Distance(40), new Distance(30), new Distance(120)
    );

list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(d -> d.getTotalDistance() / 50));

list.stream().mapToInt(Distance::getTotalDistance).forEach(System.out::println); // assuming the getter for 'totalDistance'
```

***Output***:

> ```
> 1
> 40
> 30
> 130
> 100
> 120
> ```

Comment: Just edited to clarify further in the example and the print `list` wouldn't print the values, hence updated that as well.

Comment: We can conclude from the question that the method’s name is `totalDistance`, not `getTotalDistance`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you are looking for, Use 'Backed Collection' concept of Java Collections.

```
 List<Distance> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Distance(100));
        list.add(new Distance(10));
        list.add(new Distance(1));
        list.add(new Distance(40));
        list.add(new Distance(30));

List<Distance> backedList=list.subList(<int indexFrom>,<int indexTo>);  //backed List- which is backed by original collection, Any change done in backedList will reflect in Original List

Collections.sort(backedList);        // Assuming Comparable is implemented in Distance
```

Now Original list will have sorted within range with unsorted elements outside range

Note:- It does not use java8

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
List<Distance> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Distance(100));
        list.add(new Distance(10));
        list.add(new Distance(1));
        list.add(new Distance(40));
        list.add(new Distance(30));

        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list1 -> list1.stream().sorted().limit(50));
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

output for the same will be -

```
Distance [distance=100]
Distance [distance=10]
Distance [distance=1]
Distance [distance=40]
Distance [distance=30]
```